# Uso de corchetes [ ] en consultas SOQL en Apex

Tags: apex

```
Account[] accts = [SELECT Name,Phone FROM Account 
                   WHERE (Name='SFDC Computing' AND NumberOfEmployees>25)
                   ORDER BY Name
                   LIMIT 10];
System.debug(accts.size() + ' account(s) returned.');
// Write all account array info
System.debug(accts);
```

estoy aprendiendo apex y quisiera saber porque se pone `[]` despues de `account`

```
for (variable_list : [soql_query]) {
    code_block
}
```

los dos puntos despues para que sirven en apex si alguien me pudiera explicar

Comment: Pon en el título _cuál es la pregunta_. Lee [ask].

Comment: Si algua de las dos respuestas responde a tu pregunta no te olvides de marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa. Mírate [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para aprender a aceptar respuestas válidas a tu pregunta. Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Se ponen los dos corchetes [], porque será un array. Es decir un conjunto de objetos de tipo Account en este caso.

Despues está el accts.size() que te indicará el numero de objetos devueltos.

Comment: Claaaro ahora entiendo muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta la tienes en la [documentación sobre cómo incluir consultas SOQL](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/es-MX/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql#:%7E:text=To%20include%20SOQL%20queries%20within,an%20array%20of%20Account%20sObjects.)

> Para incluir consultas SOQL en su código Apex, incluya la instrucción SOQL entre corchetes y asigne el valor devuelto a un conjunto de sObjects. Por ejemplo, lo siguiente recupera todos los registros de cuenta con dos campos (Name y Phone) y devuelve un conjunto de sObjects de cuenta.

```
Account[] accts = [SELECT Name,Phone FROM Account];
```